# How to detect input audio existence and do action whenever it exists?

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I checked **pyaudio** but it offers the ability to record the input and manipulate it , i just want to do action when audio input exists.

Comment: What is your use case - any sound detection or speech detection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple input audio detection by using `PyAudio`. You just need to decide what you mean with audio existence.

In the following example code I have used a simple [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) calculation with a threshold. An other option is a peak test, just comparing the amplitude of each audio sample with a peak amplitude threshold. What is most useful for you depends on the application.

You can play around with the threshold value (i.e. the minimum amplitude or loudness of audio) and the chunk size (i.e. the latency of the audio detection) to get the behaviour you want.

```py
import pyaudio
import math

RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
AUDIO_EXISTENCE_THRESHOLD = 1000

def detect_input_audio(data, threshold):
    if not data:
        return False
    rms = math.sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in data]) / len(data))
    if rms > threshold:
        return True
    return False

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, input=True,
                    rate=RATE, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

data = []
while detect_input_audio(data, AUDIO_EXISTENCE_THRESHOLD):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)

# Do something when input audio exists
# ...

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

Comment: thank you for reply @arghol . i want to use the script for audio detection whenever im in a game that doesn't have the "open mic" option , so the script detects whenever i speak (audio input) and i use another lib to make key presses on the talking hotkey in game

Comment: Ok! Then you need something called [voice activity detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) (VAD) or speech detection. I recommend you to update your question with this information.

Comment: It is possible to use the simple root mean square method in my answer as a crude voice activity detection. You need to adjust the threshold value so it is larger than background noise and lower than most speech, though.

Comment: Also, check out this [Github repository](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad).